# How to include .aar library into android library .aar file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am unable to distribute single library.

I have a library **Main** which is using library **Base**. Now I need to distribute only single **Main** Library which will be used in an application project.

To use **Main** library in an application project, gradle is asking to add **Base** library as a dependency as well.

Will this help?

1)

```
I think Main library should have base library in it. So when I look at the sizes:
Base library : 5 MB
Main library : 500 kb
```

To use single library, I think Main Library's size should be 5.5 MB.

2)

or is there any code problem to use Main library in application project? through which, there is no need to add Base library as dependency.

**Explaining Again** :

Current Scenario -

```
Application project
              :
              :
     (depends):----> Main Library
              :
              :
              -----> Base Library
```

Where it should be -

```
Application project
              :
              :                (internally depends upon)
     (depends):---------> Main Library ------------> Base Library
```

Comment: How do you add the aar file? As a maven dependency or a flar file?

Comment: I have added aar files as a flat file. 
Process to add :- Right click on project, click on “Open Module Settings”. Import .AAR Package, then in dependencies tab add aar as module dependency.

Comment: The aar file doesn't contain the transitive dependencies.You have to add them or you have to use a maven repo.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable and helpful suggestion. It fixed my issue.

I moved from flat to maven.

Above issue has been fixed if I use public maven repo (refer from below link)
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

However, As I am using the library internally and thus I need to make it private, I tried with setup private maven repo. ( refer from )
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en
Now, I have same issue with private maven repo as well. I have two compile dependencies.

Comment: Check this (`pom.withXml section`): https://github.com/JeroenMols/ArtifactoryExample/blob/master/AwesomeAdvancedLibrary/awesomeadvancedlibrary/build.gradle